# Reload all fonts without restarting a SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on a font testing tool. On mac, when you edit the design of a font and want to reflect the change in an app, you need to restart it.

Is there a SwiftUI method to reload system fonts?

Thanks.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. How do you expect any UI Framework to know?

Comment: Dude wants to reload a font after the font file changed on disk. I don't see how an MRE is required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can tell SwiftUI (or UIKit or AppKit) to reload a font in a way that updates existing font objects or discards cached fonts.

What you can do is load the font data from the file yourself on command and create a [`CGFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfont) from the data using [`CGFont.init(_:DataProvider)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfont/1396367-init). Once you have the newly-loaded `CGFont`, you can turn it into a [`CTFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfont-q6r) using [`CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1508745-ctfontcreatewithgraphicsfont). `CTFont` is toll-free-bridged with [`UIFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont) and [`NSFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont), so you can turn it in to one of those with a cast: `ctFont as UIFont` or `ctFont as NSFont`. You can also construct a SwiftUI [`Font`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font) using [`Font.init(_:CTFont)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/init(_:)).